# Trying to use Collections.sort to sort my array with no luck

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, compiler-errors

I've made the array bellow and have no luck sorting it

```
String[] albums = {"Abbey Road - Beatles","Thriller - Michael Jackson",
    "Queen - News of the World","Gimme Shelter - The Rolling Stones",
    "Pink Floyd - The Dark Side of the Moon"};
```

Using Collections.sort(albums); gives the error: no suitable method for sort(String[])

I've imported java.util.*; but this error is still persisting

I'm still learning and don't understand how to fix this or what I'm missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an array (not a `Collection`). You can use [`Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<? super T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) to sort it. Like,

```
Arrays.sort(albums, Comparator.naturalOrder());
```